# How to report error in MSDN Docs?

Tags: .net, wcf, msdn

Is there anyway to report an error in the MSDN docs? I know there is a way to do this in the MySQL docs.

I was recently reviewing some specifications on Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and I came across this:

> Typically, you can use transport security when your client is deployed
>   over the Internet, as it provides end-to-end security.

This is factually incorrect as transport security provides *point-to-point* security. It's in a section about *Message Security in WCF* where it jumps to start referring to transport security in a couple of sentences and then back again to message security. It would be unfortunate if someone became confused by this.

Here is the [source document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx). Is there anyway to report this typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the bottom of the page, there is a question "Did you find this helpful?". If you click "No", a form appears where you can leave feedback. One of the options you can select is "Not accurate".